# How to select 1st maximum and second maximum in time series data

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to detect shift start hour using time series data and SQL code.

My developed code is able to detect the start time of the first shift while discarding the second shift. My question here is: How do I select the second maximum after 6 hours of the first detected maximum (start time of the first shift).

BTW: I have used the next code:

```
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by t8.Process_ID, t8.Store order by t8.number_items DESC ) = 1
```

Here is more details, normally at the start of the shift each worker will use one item and therefore the number of items will be very high at the start of each shift. As I mentioned before, by selecting the first maximum that corresponds to highest number of items it gives me the time of the first shift.

My code works on several iterations:

1. Iteration 1: I have the next data of two months (after performing some processing ofc)

| Process_id | Item_id | Store | Date | Start_time | End_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prod_x | MS34XX | store1 | 2022-01-01 | 6:30 | 12:45 |
| Prod_X | MS36YX | store1 | 2022-01-02 | 6:30 | 13:00 |
| Prod_X | MS58YX | store1 | 2022-01-01 | 6:15 | 13:00 |
| Prod_X | MS58YX | store2 | 2022-01-01 | 6:15 | 12:00 |
| Prod_X | MS60YY | store2 | 2022-01-01 | 6:15 | 12:30 |
| Prod_X | MS61YY | store2 | 2022-01-02 | 6:00 | 12:30 |
| Prod_X | MS61YY | store2 | 2022-01-03 | 6:15 | 12:30 |
| Prod_X | MSS7YY | store2 | 2022-01-01 | 14:15 | 20:45 |
| Prod_X | MSS8YY | store2 | 2022-01-02 | 14:15 | 21:00 |
| Prod_X | MSS8YY | store2 | 2022-01-03 | 14:00 | 20:45 |

and

2. Iteration 2:

| Process_id | Store | Start_time | number_items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prod_x | store1 | 6:30 | 2 |
| Prod_X | store1 | 6:15 | 1 |
| Prod_X | store2 | 6:15 | 3 |
| Prod_X | store2 | 6:00 | 1 |
| Prod_X | store2 | 14:15 | 2 |
| Prod_X | store2 | 14:00 | 1 |

so in STORE 1: the first shift starts at 6:15 and in the second shift starts at 14:15

The same for the end shift

Comment: Better add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: As @ADITYAPAWAR says, I'd love to help (if you can share some sample data and expected results)

Comment: @Felipe Hoffa here is

Comment: So what's the correct answer? Maybe `store1-6:15; store2-6:00; store2-14:15;` or did I misunderstand the sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below and let me know if this works for your case.

If those last two calculated columns are not needed just wrap in another cte and select required

```
with first_shift_details as(
select * ,
min(start_time) over(partition by process_id,store order by start_time) first_shift
from shifts
order by 1,2,3
)
select *
,min(case when datediff('hour',first_shift,start_time) > 6 then start_time else null end ) over(partition by process_id,store order by start_time) second_shift
from first_shift_details
qualify start_time = first_shift or start_time = second_shift
;
```